# Setting the cookies for forge.request.ajax in Trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

I'm trying to set an extra cookie in the forge.request.ajax call. Is there a way to dot this?

Comment: An additional cookie value (modifying an existing cookie)?  Or adding a new cookie?

Comment: Hmmm... jQuery has a pre-request callback function - beforeSend.

Comment: I'm using forge.request.ajax. I'm not sure that the pre-request will work. I'm adding an extra cookie. It also appears that calling document.cookie does nothing in this respect. I did get it working with "forge run web" by mimicing the weird cookie storage it does for the node.js proxy, but this doesn't work on my Android.

Comment: I ended up having to setup a proxy for what I was doing unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `headers` argument to request.ajax manually if you wanted, e.g.

```
window.forge.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://my.server.com/protected/,
  headers: {
    'COOKIE': 'csrftoken=47ac86bb7965b343e8ca21343b164ef3',
  },
  success: function (data) { },
  error: function (error) { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this has any effect.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried the above on Android and iOS and they both set a cookie on the server side...

Comment: Pretty certain. I was using `forge run android` not `forge run web` if that makes a difference. The second problem there may be is I need a combination of a server provided session Id and a manually set cookie, so I can't set the entire cookie string.

Comment: OK, if this method isn't working for you we'll add a new option to manually set cookies on requests. It's in our backlog - I'll update this question when we're ready to deploy.

Comment: really need this functionality as well

Answer (score 0):

Making requests through forge.request.ajax actually uses a whole different context to your JavaScript - this is to get around the cross-domain restrictions that can be imposed on normal JavaScript.

We don't currently allow for manually settings cookies in the forge.request context, but note that any cookies which are set as part of a request will be persisted (as applicable) to subsequent requests, so we weren't expecting people to have to set their values by hand...

Comment: Unfortunately there are some bad APIs out there. Having full control of Tue request header its very handy.